# Why does Jelly Bean no longer support Flash?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, adobe-flash

I am fine with the news that Android Jelly Bean no longer supports Flash. But being an Android developer, I am surprised that they did not release a reason for that.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adobe decided to stop support for its Flash Player on Android mainly because of HTML5 doesn't need flash player to play videos. Unfortunately, that didn't mean all Web sites you visit would start using HTML5 instead of Flash (though it would have been nice). If some of the Web sites you want to look at are using Flash, the last version of Adobe Flash Player that landed on the Google Play Store will work with your Jelly Bean device.
 However, since it's no longer available through the Play Store, you'll need to install it from a side-loaded APK.
**They've only stopped support, doesn't mean that it won't work but if it doesn't on certain devices then they won't fix it or support it.**

You can still install it from [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#Flash%20Player%20archives).

Comment: Rather than downloading the Flash player APK from a 3rd party site, you can still download it direct from Adobe, go to http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#Flash%20Player%20archives and scroll down to the "Flash Player for Android 4.0 archives" section, there's even a newer version listed than on your other site.

Answer (score 5):

It's not that Jelly Bean won't support Flash. Adobe decided not to support Flash for newer devices, starting from Jelly Bean and onwards. I don't know the know the reason though. Maybe they got tired of testing (and certifying) several devices?

[Source](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/11/09/adobe-stops-development-of-flash-for-mobile-browsers-and-its-official/).

You can still install Flash on Jelly Bean; there are [workarounds](http://better-tablet.com/18/11/how-to-install-adobe-flash-player-on-android-4-14-2-jelly-bean-2/) for that.

Comment: The reason, perhaps not expressed officially, was because they never could get good performance from the technology on a mobile platform.