# Is Adobe Flash deprecated with regards to Android Devices and Apps?

Tags: applications, adobe-flash

I'm looking at all the cool new Android tablets, but the ones that really catch my eye (with regards to size, resolution, processor, and memory) don't seem to support Adobe Flash. Like the [Barnes & Noble - NOOK HD+ BNTV600](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Barnes-&-Noble---NOOK-HD+-Tablet-with-32GB-Memory---Slate/6412767.p;tab=specifications?id=1218737497929&skuId=6412767), At least Best Buy says they don't (I haven't looked into much yet.) Most of the devices I've been interested in run Android v4.0 and seem to have good processor/memory specs.

I haven't done any flash type programming in a very long time. However I do want to get more involved with Android products/app development. If it's just a software/driver type issue or something that can be overcome by some tweaking I'm fine with that. However if Flash plays a big role then I should probably just get a device that supports it!

So my question is, how necessary is Adobe Flash, and in most cases (for devices that don't support it out of the box,) is it addable/installable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe Flash has been deprecated starting Jelly Bean, for reasons only Adobe knows. However, there are still workarounds for installing Flash.

The trend in mobile (Android) development now is using native Android, or HTML5. Flash is discouraged, although there are still Flash websites around. Phones with older versions of Android may be able to access them.

Related: [Why does Jelly Bean no longer support Flash?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39138/why-does-jelly-bean-no-longer-support-flash)

Comment: Sweet, that's exactly what I wanted to hear! Thanks